# Applying the dbar operator to differentiate a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, cauchy-riemann-equations

I'm trying to differentiate this complex function
$$ f(z) = (|z|-1)^2 $$
in order to determine where it satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equation $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}} = 0$.

So I first differentiate with respect to z. (When I calculate it, I differentiate "as if z is real" -- is that correct?)
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = 2 (\lvert z\rvert -1) \frac{z}{\lvert z \rvert} $$

And then [according to this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBAR_problem), I can calculate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}$ by taking the complex conjugate of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$:
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}} = 2 (\lvert z\rvert -1) \frac{\bar{z}}{\lvert z \rvert} $$

However, the correct answer is supposed to be
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}} = 2 (\lvert z\rvert -1) \frac{z}{ \bar{z}} $$

Where am I going wrong?  Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Since $|z|^{2} = z\bar{z}$, the chain rule gives $2|z|\, \partial |z|/\partial\bar{z} = z$, or $\partial |z|/\partial\bar{z} = z/(2|z|)$. Applying the chain rule to your function, $\partial f/\partial\bar{z} = 2(|z| - 1)z/(2|z|)$. So, I agree with you (except a factor of $2$ appears to have gotten lost when you differentiated $|z| = \sqrt{z\bar{z}}$).

Comment: I see -- thank you!  Now I'm also getting $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}} = (\lvert z\rvert -1) \frac{\bar{z}}{\lvert z \rvert}$.  Perhaps then the teacher's class notes were just incorrect, or else I'm misunderstanding something else.  In any case..thank you!